# How to draw child controls and custom drawings in expected order?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, custom-controls

I have control with custom drawings, let's call it `Surface`.

I want to embed some winforms controls into that `Surface`. But also I want to draw some custom drawings (connectors), depending on controls location, size, etc.

I tried to give the responsibility to draw those connectors to child controls themselves, so any of my child control was just bigger in size and included all the necessary drawings. I used `Parent.InvokePaint` call to draw parent background when needed (and I also tried transparent background).

**The drawback**: when parent background is painted inside child `OnPaint` event it erases all the other same controls already painted. The picture below shows the result. Colored areas are the child controls content.

[image]

I also tried to give the responsibility to draw connectors to `Surface` and add child controls to `Surface.Controls` list.

**The drawback**: child control are always drawn on top of my custom drawing (which happens in `Surface.OnPaint`), because their painting happens somewhen later in the queue.

[image]

My requirements are:

I need workable controls inside my `Surface` (receiving any mouse and keyboard event, focusable, etc). Every control would have some custom-drawn connectors to show context on surface. And when controls are overlapped I want everything to appear in expected order.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found simple solution to my problem.

I've just used Region property of child control (popup) to setup clipping path:

```
GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
// add some shapes to path here, describing the control shape
// ...
this.Region = new Region(path);
```

I didn't know about custom path clipping before.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to adjust the z-order of controls on a WinForm, you can use the controls' `SendToFront` and `SendToBack` methods.  A better solution is to go to the control's container.  There in the container's `Controls` property is the `SetChildIndex` method that can then independently set the z-order of its contained controls.

Comment: I already use this, for example when I pick the control I put it on front, but the problem is with transparent areas.

Comment: Does this mean that I must realize all the functionality, that is built in to winforms, when it comes to fill my containers with textboxes, labels, scrollbar panels, etc??

Comment: I don't know about etc, but - labels are simple Graphics.DrawString, scrollbars will be added as child controls since they are at the edge and aren't 'transparent', you can create ad-hoc textboxes when user will have to input something, and so on.

Comment: well, I got your point. That's really I suppose to do. We are dealing with first case here (pic #1). How I should setup my custom control so that instead of parent backround in place of red ellipse there is also part of control that's behind? These are different controls, and I don't want to merge them into one. I guess I'm clear now.

Comment: If I understand correctly what is the case here, you would better want to include "control that's behind" to be the part of your control.

Comment: I found simple solution to my problem, as described in my answer. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

@Dimitry - thanks for the C# information.  This question really helped me to get started on putting a custom graphic onto a Custom Control.  However, I am using Visual Basic .NET so here is some more detail and a VB perspective.  The Zorder in which graphics are placed on the surface is also critical. This is because there is no way of changing the z-order of Drawing2D Objects such as .GrahicsPath and .FillRectangle; only the Zorder of Controls can be changed.   To hide part of an existing Control, and paint an arrow over it, the steps are as follows.  The whole Method should be placed in the Paint Event of the Control; care then needs to be taken to make sure that the Paint Event is triggered whenever the Control is redrawn (that's another story!):

1. Create a Graphics object attached to the Control
2. Refresh the Control
3. Fill a rectangle to hide part of the Control's existing info.
4. Create & set the shape desired as a Clipping Mask (in the code example below, an Arrow)
5. Fill the shape with the desired Color/image, or whatever is required.

In the example below, applied within a Custom Control based on a ListView, an arrow is created and placed on the left of the header.  It obscures an unwanted CheckBox, leaves the the ones required in view, and looks like this:

[image: ![ListView overlaid with Custom Arrow that obscures an unwanted CheckBox.]
A few years have passed since you posted your question and the previous answer.  Perhaps the good information that is now in the .NET help was added since then. Find it is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-clipping-with-a-region) with further detail and links.

---

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)       'This is traps the default OnPaint for a Component, so it starts by calling the Base's Paint Event
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)

    'Add your custom paint code here - in this example, a Green Arrow
    AddArrowOverHeaderCheckBox()        
End Sub
Private Sub AddArrowOverHeaderCheckBox()
    'Adds an Arrow that is placed over the Checkbox of the 0th row, of a ListView, (over a Row that is used as a Header in this Custom Control).

    'Create a Rectangle into which to put the arrow
    Dim G As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics               'Attach a Graphics Object to the Base
    Dim lvsi As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem = Me.Items(0).SubItems(0)   'Get the first row; it is being used as a header in this case
    Dim CheckBoxWidth As Integer = Me.Bounds.X          'Calculate the size of the Control's CheckBox
    Dim CheckBoxHeight As Integer = lvsi.Bounds.Height
    Dim InflateBy As Integer = 1                        'Optional amount to resize the area in which the Arrow is to be placed
    Me.Refresh()                                        'Refresh the ListViewTab so that it does not overpaint the arrow that is about to be created at the End Sub
    Dim I As Integer = 0
    I = (CheckBoxHeight + 1) Mod 2
    Dim R As Rectangle = New Rectangle(lvsi.Bounds.X + Me.Margin.Left, lvsi.Bounds.Top, CheckBoxWidth, CheckBoxHeight + I) 'Make sure the height is an Odd number, to make a tidy arrow
    'myBrush.Color = Color.Red
    R.Inflate(InflateBy * 2, InflateBy)                  'Create a covering rectangle that is larger than the CheckBox on the Left of the CheckView Item in both dimensions
    Dim myBrush As New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Me.BackColor)
    G.FillRectangle(myBrush, R)                         'Draw a filled Rectangle over the CheckBox in the Background colour for the ListViewTab to obscure the CheckBox
    Dim RW = R.Width
    Dim RH = R.Height
    I = CSng(RH) * 0.5 \ 2                              'Set a proportion of the arrow's width for its shaft, here 50%
    If RH Mod 2 <> 0 Then RH += 1                       'Ensure that the Height is an Odd number to make the Arrow axially symmetric
    '                                                   'Create a polygon in an Arrow shape that fits inside the Rectangle
    Dim polyArrow As Point() = {New Point(R.X + 0, I + R.Y), New Point(R.X + RW * 0.4, I + R.Y), New Point(R.X + RW * 0.4, 0 + R.Y), New Point(R.X + RW, RH * 0.5 + R.Y),
                                New Point(R.X + RW * 0.4, RH + R.Y), New Point(R.X + RW * 0.4, RH - I + R.Y), New Point(R.X + 0, RH - I + R.Y)}
    Dim path As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()            'Create a Path shaped like an Arrow & sized proportionately to the size of the required Rectangle
    path.AddPolygon(polyArrow)                          'Turn the Path into a polygon
    Dim [reg] As New [Region](path)                     'Define a Graphics Region of the shape of the Arrow
    G.SetClip([reg], combineMode:=Drawing2D.CombineMode.Replace) 'Redefine the area; clipping will now prevent any drawing outside the area of the Arrow
    myBrush.Color = Color.Green
    G.FillRectangle(myBrush, R)                         'Draw a filled Green Rectangle, clipped to the Path shape
    'Dim pen As Pen = Pens.Black                         'Optionally: Draw a fine boundary in black
    'G.DrawPath(pen, path)                               'Optionally: Draw a fine boundary in black
    G.SetClip(Me.ClientRectangle)                       'Remove the Clip from the Graphics area - in case G is re-used
    myBrush.Dispose()                                   'Tidy up
    G.Dispose()
End Sub
```

---